# Switch case statement in coffee script

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript, switch-statement

I have a few different buttons that are calling the same function and I would like to have them wrapped in a switch statement instead of using a bunch of else if conditions. Any help would be great!!!

```
events:
"click .red, .blue, #black, #yellow" : "openOverlay"

openOverlay: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()

target = $(e.currentTarget)

# the view should be opened
view = 
  if target.hasClass 'red' then new App.RedView
  else if target.hasClass 'blue' then new App.BlueView
  else if target.is '#black' then new App.BlackView
  else
    null

# Open the view
App.router.overlays.add view: view if view?
```

Comment: It's not suitable for a switch statement anyway (hasClass vs is).

Answer (score 117, accepted):

There are two forms of [`switch`](http://coffeescript.org/#switch) in CoffeeScript:

```
switch expr
    when expr1 then ...
    when expr2 then ...
    ...
    else ...
```

and:

```
switch
    when expr1 then ...
    when expr2 then ...
    ...
    else ...
```

The second form might help you:

```
view = switch
  when target.hasClass 'red' then new App.RedView
  when target.hasClass 'blue' then new App.BlueView
  when target.is '#black' then new App.BlackView
  else null
```

You could leave out the `else null` if `undefined` is an acceptable value for `view`. You could also wrap the logic in an (explicit) function:

```
viewFor = (target) ->
    # There are lots of ways to do this...
    return new App.RedView   if(target.hasClass 'red')
    return new App.BlueView  if(target.hasClass 'blue')
    return new App.BlackView if(target.is '#black')
    null

view = viewFor target
```

Giving your logic a name (i.e. wrapping it in a function) is often useful for clarifying your code.

Comment: Beware that the `then` must **only** be used in one-line assignation. Don't put a `then` if you write your code below or it will fail during the compilation.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the details in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23046594/167251), `switch` statements in CoffeeScript also supports `,` to provide multiple match results:

```
switch someVar
    when val3, val4 then ...
    else ...
```

or (if your statements has multiple lines):

```
switch someVar
    when val3, val4
        ...
    else
        ...
```

Comment: I don't think`or` is right here - it will create `case (val1 || val2):` statement - ie. running a boolean operation on `val1` and `val2`-  which is not what I'd be expecting here. The `,` does the trick though.

Comment: @Voy: you are right - `or` doesn't produce the desired result. Answer updated