# Theoretical Coffeescript Switch Statement Conundrum

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, switch-statement, theory

## preface

This probably has no real implementation but after reading [another post on coffeescript's 2 switch usages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046257/switch-case-statement-in-coffee-script), I decided to play around with it and found this rather odd issue.

## coffeescript

```
type = 'guidance'

s = switch
  when type is 'guidance'
   'g'
  when type is 'vulnerability'
   'v'
  else
   'foo'

console.log s #g
```

## transpiled javascript

```
var s, type;

type = 'guidance';

s = (function() {
  switch (false) {
    case type !== 'guidance':
     return 'g';
  case type !== 'vulnerability':
     return 'v';
  default:
     return 'foo';
 }
})();

console.log(s); //g
```

## the conundrum

What I don't get is that the case expressions are being compiled to the opposite value. The Coffeescript `when type is 'guidance'` *should* transpile to the following javascript `case type === 'guidance'` right?

If you use `s = switch true` then the case expressions are rendered correctly `case type === 'guidance'`.  Regardless of the rendered javaScript case expressions, the result is the same.

Comment: Please re-read your question. The code transpiles to the exact thing you say it should transpile to.

Comment: That's a typo from copying and pasting. It has been corrected

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a "conundrum". The transpiled result works and it's just the way coffeescript decided to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call this an issue, because it works as expected :-)

For the reason, I can only guess (maybe there are some comments in the compiler). It is most likely that they needed to cast all of these expressions to boolean values - they want it to work like an `if` statement, but `switch` does use the `===` operator to compare with the given value. So you can't do

```
switch (true) {
    case 1: …
    case []: …
    case "true": …
}
```

because none of those would work, while all of them are truthy values. So you can use the [double not operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1048572):

```
switch (true) {
    case !!( 1 ): …
    case !!( [] ): …
    case !!( "true" ): …
}
```

and any of those expressions would match `true`. However, you can reduce your code size a bit by moving the outer `!` to the other side of the comparision (`!true`), and get the equivalent

```
switch (false) {
    case !( 1 ): …
    case !( [] ): …
    case !( "true" ): …
}
```

You can see this exact pattern in the [coffeescript docs](http://coffeescript.org/#switch). Now, apparently the compiler is clever enough to compose the `!` on an `==` or `===` expression to `!=` or `!==`, but this doesn't work for arbitrary expressions.

If you ask me, they just should've compiled this to a series of `if else`s.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, the Coffeescript transpiler generates a `switch` statement to match the explicit value `false`, not `true`. Thus, the `case` expressions are the opposite of what the `when` clauses say. When the expression in the `when` clause is `true`, the generated `switch` statement will pick that `case` because it's looking for the *opposite* condition to be `false`.

Comment: I can offer no insight into *why* it works that way.

Comment: That's kinda what I'm seeking is the *why*... then again this is all just *talking shop* so it's not really useful code aside from being able to execute different *contextual* return values from the expressions.

Comment: @jusopi, if you're looking for the *why*, maybe visit `#coffeescript` on http://freenode.net and ask there.